# read csv with column-name x value pairs

Tags: csv, pandas, dictionary, dataframe, import

I have a long (csv) file with "column-name x value" pairs which I would like to read into a pandas.DataFrame

```
user_id   col  val
00008901    1   55
00008901    2   66
00011501    1   77
00011501    3   88
00011501    4   99
```

The result should look like this:

```
             1   2    3   4
00008901    55  66    0   0
00011501    77   0   88  99
```

I tried to read it into a list and create a DataFrame from it, but pandas crashed as I have 4.5 million elements.

What the best way to do that? Ideally directly with read_csv.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First use [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) for create `DataFrame`:

```
 df = pd.to_csv('file.csv')
```

Then  need [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html):

```
df1 = df.set_index(['user_id','col'])['val'].unstack(fill_value=0)
print (df1)
col       1   2   3   4
user_id                
8901     55  66   0   0
11501    77   0  88  99
```

Another solution with [`pivot`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html), replacing `NaN` to `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html) and last cast to `int`:

```
df1 = df.pivot(index='user_id', columns='col', values='val').fillna(0).astype(int)
print (df1)
col       1   2   3   4
user_id                
8901     55  66   0   0
11501    77   0  88  99
```

If get error:

> "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

It means you have some duplicates, so fastest solution is `groupby` with `unstack` and some aggreagte function like `mean` or `sum`:

```
print (df.groupby(['user_id','col'])['val'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0))
col       1   2   3   4
user_id                
8901     55  66   0   0
11501    77   0  88  99
```

Better it see in a bit changed `csv`:

```
print (df)
   user_id  col  val
0     8901    1   55
1     8901    2   66
2    11501    1   77 > duplicates -> 11501 and 1
3    11501    1  151 > duplicates -> 11501 and 1
4    11501    3   88
5    11501    4   99


print (df.groupby(['user_id','col'])['val'].mean().unstack(fill_value=0))
col        1   2   3   4
user_id                 
8901      55  66   0   0
11501    114   0  88  99
```

Actually I thought I had no duplicates, but found out that I really have some ...
I could not use ".mean" as it is categorial value, but solved the problem by first looking at the sorted table and then just keeping the last entry ... then applying the (great !) solution .. which I still have to fully understand ;-)

```
df.sort(columns=(['user_id','col']) ) # optional for debugging
df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id','col'], keep='last', inplace=True)
df_table = df.set_index(['user_id','col'])['val'].unstack(fill_value=0)
```

Comment: wow, that's already a cool approach which I haven't found in days! The problem is that I get an error when unstacking > "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape"

Comment: See updated solution, I try explain problem and get solution.

Comment: Great solution which I could not find in days! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks, only one improvement `df.sort(columns=(['user_id','col']))` is nice in old version of pandas, in newer get `FutureWarning: sort(columns=....) is deprecated, use sort_values(by=.....)`, so the best is use `df.sort_values(['user_id','col'], inplace=True)`

Comment: had to change df = df[df.duplicated(keep='last')] to df = df.drop_duplicates(keep='last') and now I get the error again, although it removed quite some duplicates. "ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" ... strange

Comment: I am not sure, but it seems you need define columns where check duplicates like `df = df.drop_duplicates(subset=['user_id','col'], keep='last')`. The best is test it in small data sample and then apply solution to all data. Another possible problem is `whitespaces` in column, you can remove them by `df['user_id'] = df['user_id'].str.strip()`

Comment: But maybe simplier is use `last` function like `print (df.groupby(['user_id','col'])['val'].last().unstack(fill_value=0))` - but `drop_duplicates` can be faster.

Comment: You are right! I also want to remove the rows with the same ['user_id','col'] which assigns a new value (although that should actually not happen in my dataset). Default for df.drop_duplicates is "all columns" which would only remove rows which would assign the same value again. Now it is working! Thanks a lot!!!!

Comment: Supeeeer, glad can help you. ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly read in the required structure using read_csv. But you can use [pivot_table](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html) function to convert to the desired structure.

```
df = pd.read_csv('filepath/your.csv')
df = pd.pivot_table(df, index='user_id', columns='col', values='val, aggfunc='mean').reset_index()

The output will be like
             1   2    3   4
00008901    55  66    0   0
00011501    77   0   88  99
```

Comment: Looks like an interesting alternative. In my case, I just can't use 'mean' as I have categorical values, but need just to keep the last one (see above).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it is possible to use `read_csv` to parse the csv file.

You can create a data structure such as dictionary and use it to create a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

data_dict = defaultdict(lambda: [0] * columns)
columns = 4
delimiter = ','

with open("my_csv.csv") as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file,delimiter=delimiter)
    for row in reader:
        row_id = row["user_id"]
        col = int(row["col"])-1
        val = int(row["val"])
        data_dict[row_id][col] = val

df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict.values(), index=data_dict.keys(), columns=range(1, columns+1))
```

For a csv file that contains:

```
user_id,col,val
00008901,1,55
00008901,2,66
00011501,1,77
00011501,3,88
00011501,4,99
```

The output is:

```
           1   2   3   4
00008901  55  66   0   0
00011501  77   0  88  99
```